# How to train our brain to see everything in slow motion?

Tags: vision, brain-training

People who had near death experience often found that they were able to see everything in slow motion and capture every details in their surrounding at that particular period. Because the brain process a lot of information at that time due to adrenaline in the blood to aid our chances of survival. So is there a way to train the brain to increase its processing capacity so we can perceive things like mentioned above all the time.

Comment: Often I would prefer to have a "fast forward" feature on my brain. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an article that explains that the time warp during near death experiences is an illusion. http://www.livescience.com/2117-time-slow-emergencies.html In such situations, the mind captures more memories of the event. "And the more memory you have of an event, the longer you believe it took."

Comment: So according to that article we just hold more memories of that incident so we get the illusion of slowing time. (Consider something is going to hit you hard) Does that mean we cannot do anything out of the blue at that instant to dodge or save ourself from getting hurt ,but instead we could do only what it is humanly possible and hold memories of time slowing down?